# What questions should I expect during an EASA skill test?

Tags: flight-training, easa-regulations, checkride

I have my skill test in few days. I'm lost on what are the questions that will be asked during the oral part of the atpl skill test.

Comment: It would help if you told us what kind of license you're getting... I'm sure the questions are different for private, commercial, ATP, helicopter, sea planes, etc.

Comment: That would be great, I'm getting atpl license from Greece.

Answer (score 1):

Goodness, the best not guess, since the amount of information an ATPL candidate must master is just massive. Could be anything from the smallest detail to broad concepts. Anything to make you uncomfortable and see if you are willing to admit that you might not yet know everything, or whether are you the kind of guy who takes the best guess and hopes it's the right one...

For your sake I hope all goes well, and for everybody elses, I hope you know everything needed to become a safe professional airline pilot. Godspeed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/48977)

Comment: @dalearn I'd disagree... question is, what to expect; answer is, expect a very broad range. That's an answer, and more reasonable than one that attempts to list all that might be asked.

Comment: @dalearn Honestly, I do deeply sympathize with the anxiety of the asker, but I answered just  as honestly, since it would be misleading to give any kind of listing of possible or likely question he or any ATPL student might face. This is the least speculative answer anyone can give. Some questions do not have definitive answers.